# Galleria: Layer containing links not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, galleria

I'm using the all new HTML layer feature introduced in 1.2.5 of the [galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) jquery plugin. It works just fine but as soon as there is an <a> tag in the markup, no layer at all is being displayed. Here's my markup:

```
<div id="galleria">
    <a href="feature-image.jpg" class="link">
        <img title="feature" alt="" src="feature-thumbnail.jpg" class="image" />
        <div class="layer">
            <h3>subtitle</h3>
            <h2>title</h2>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.example.com">read more...</a></p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    dataConfig: function(img) {
        return {
            layer: $(img).siblings('.layer').html()
        };
    }
});
```

Anyone having an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please review markup you've posted - there is no *#galleria* element there, and neither is *.layer* element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, my guess is that it's not working as expected because the div `.layer` is inside <a> element which it shouldn't. Try to reorder your html to this:

```
<div id="galleria">
    <a href="feature-image.jpg" class="link">
        <img title="feature" alt="" src="feature-thumbnail.jpg" class="image" />
    </a>
    <div class="layer">
        <h3>subtitle</h3>
        <h2>title</h2>
        <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.example.com">read more...</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then your galleria code would be:

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    dataConfig: function(img) {
        return {
            layer: $(img).parent().next().html()
        };
    }
});
```